# Javascript .indexOf matching HTML symbols

Tags: javascript, symbols, indexof

I solved a problem in a very sloppy manner, looking for a better solution.

**Task**

Check if a span contains an HTML symbol(an arrow), if present, replace the symbol with it's opposite.

**First Attempt** (not showing the second code snipet that does the reverse)

```
 first=headers[0].querySelector('span')
 if (first.innerHTML.indexOf('&searr;') !== -1)
                            first.innerHTML=first.innerHTML.substring(0, first.innerHTML.length - 13)
 first.innerHTML+='&nbsp;&nwarr;'
```

**Why doesn't that work?**

because while `&nbsp;` === `&nbsp;`
but for some reason  `&searr;` === ↘

Seriously!  Try this (tested in IE 11 and chrome)

```
<span>test</span>
<script>
    first=document.querySelector('span')
    first.innerHTML+='&nbsp&searr;'
    console.log(first.innerHTML)
</script>
```

In the console you get: `test&nbsp;↘`

**My ugly solution**

I copied the arrow into my JS code

```
if (first.innerHTML.indexOf('↘') !== -1)
                            first.innerHTML=first.innerHTML.substring(0, first.innerHTML.length - 7)
                    first.innerHTML+='&nbsp;&nwarr;'
```

So...what's the correct way of solving this issue?

Comment: What seems incorrect about your solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about having that literal arrow in your code, you shouldn't be. If your toolchain is correctly configured, it's just fine to have that literal arrow in your code.

But if you want to avoid it, you can use a unicode escape for it instead:

```
const nwarr = "\u2196";
if (first.innerHTML.indexOf(nwarr) !== -1) {
    first.innerHTML = first.innerHTML.substring(0, first.innerHTML.length - 7);
}
first.innerHTML += '&nbsp;&nwarr;'; // <== Did you mean &searr; here? The opposite of nwarr?
```

Live example (using `&searr;` in the replacement:

```js
const first = document.getElementById("first");

setTimeout(() => {
    const nwarr = "\u2196";
    if (first.innerHTML.indexOf(nwarr) !== -1) {
        first.innerHTML = first.innerHTML.substring(0, first.innerHTML.length - 7);
    }
    first.innerHTML += '&nbsp;&searr;';
}, 800);
```

```html
<span id="first">Foo&nbsp;&nwarr;</span>
```

---

Two side notes:

1. To replace things, I'd use `replace` rather than `substring` and `+=`, not least so you don't have magic numbers (13, 7) in your code:

```
first.innerHTML = first.innerHTML.replace(/\&nbsp;\u2196/g, "&nbsp;&searr;");
```

you might even allow for some browsers to use an character entity rather than character for it:

```
first.innerHTML = first.innerHTML.replace(/\&nbsp;(?:\&nwarr;|\u2196)/g, "&nbsp;&searr;");
```

Live example (using `&searr;` in the replacement:

```js
const first = document.getElementById("first");

setTimeout(() => {
    first.innerHTML = first.innerHTML.replace(/\&nbsp;(?:\&nwarr;|\u2196)/g, "&nbsp;&searr;");
}, 800);
```

```html
<span id="first">Foo&nbsp;&nwarr;</span>
```

2. I would avoid textual manipulation of `innerHTML`. If you assign to it, even when assigning back what it already had, it tears down all of the elements (and other nodes) within the element you're doing it on, and creates new, replacement elements and nodes.

For instance, you could spin through the text nodes:

```js
const first = document.getElementById("first");

setTimeout(() => {
    handleReplacement(first);
}, 800);

function handleReplacement(el) {
    for (let child = el.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 1) { // Element
            handleReplacement(child);
        } else if (child.nodeType === 3) { // Text
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/\u00A0\u2196/g, "\u00A0\u2198");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="first">Foo&nbsp;&nwarr;</span>
```

Comment: >if you're worried about having that literal arrow in your code you can use a unicode escape for it instead       =    That's some devious tricky. I could have experimented all day and not come up with that approach.

Comment: @Norsak - :-D Side note: If you ever want to know the unicode code point value for a character, `"x".charPointAt(0).toString(16)` tells you. :-)

Comment: @vatz88 - LOL, that's what I get for changing my mind half-way through writing `charAt`. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Based on T.J. Crowder's very good insights.  I patched my test code into this:

```
<span>test&nbsp;&nwarr;</span>
<script>
const nw="\u2196";
const se="\u2198";
first=document.querySelector('span')
if (first.innerHTML.indexOf(nw) !== -1)
   {
    console.log("found arrow");
    first.innerHTML = first.innerHTML.replace(/\u2196/, se);
   }

</script>
```

It still feels like we've stumbled into a messy/buggy corner of the browser world.

Comment: If your question was really, why can JS find a nbsp by looking for `'&nbsp;'` while it can't find a searr with `'&searr;'`, that wasn't very clear.